# Soft keyboard adding extra height at the bottom during onFocus of Textbox

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, soft-keyboard

In my application I have a list of textbox and textarea element, onFocus of these element **Soft Keyboard** from the phone pops up. When keyboard pops up it takes up some **amount of height in the screen**, after user enters the data he tends to close the keyboard. When keyboard is closed **the amount of height keyboard takes up when it pops up, is added at the bottom of that particular view.** This is kind of weird thing is happening.

For the reference I have added the screen shot of the problem. The first screen shot with keyboard and the second screen shot when keyboard is hidden. (This is when I get the empty space at the bottom.)

[image: First screen shot with keyboard]

Second Screen Shot

[image: Extra height added due to key board]

Here I am using AngularJS and Ionic for developing the application.

I have gone through the ionic forums but none of the solution solved this issue. Kindly let me know what I am doing wrong.

Thanks.

Comment: I add some issues with android keyboard, but nothing like that. What I did to solve my issues was to mess around with android:windowSoftInputMode, in my case it was android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" that did the trick.

Comment: The app I am developing is a Hybrid application not a native application. So I guess I cannot use the above method..??

Comment: I work with ionic. In your platform folder, you've android folder and there it is the androidmanifest file. Because your hybrid app, is wrapped with native package, so it has the same files as a native app.